# How to find the difference between 2 result sets in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find, and delete the extra records, after comparing the 2 result sets in 2 different dbs.

1) I tried with minus but it doesn't work since the records are actually the same. Minus gives a zero difference.
2) These tables are on different dbs, so rowid couldn't be compared either.

Table t1 is in db1, and another (similar) table t2 in db2.

In database db1:

```
select c1,c2 from t1;

A,09/23/2019
A,09/23/2019
B,09/22/2019
```

In database db2:

```
select c1,c2 from t2;

A,09/23/2019
A,09/23/2019
A,09/23/2019
A,09/23/2019
B,09/22/2019
B,09/22/2019
```

Desired result on db2:

```
A,09/23/2019
A,09/23/2019
B,09/22/2019
```

ie., 3 (extra) records need to be deleted on db2, basically syncing the tables. Deletes are executed from db1 via a dblink pointing to db2.

Comment: You need another column to disambiguate the identical records in each table. Don't you have a primary key in tables `t1` and `t2`?

Comment: No, there is no  primary key or unique constraints on this table. Duplicates are allowed but source & remote tables need to be in sync. These tables have 200+ million rows, so re-org will be another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have a "unique identifier" for the rows (in your DB1 and DB2 tables), you may be able to use [ROWID](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) instead.
Find the ROWIDs of the duplicates, and delete them.

First steps:
{1} use ROW_NUMBER() over (...) for "labelling" unique c1/c2 combinations
{2} find the ROWIDs of DB2
{3} use an OUTER JOIN for filtering.

```
select DB1.c1, DB1.c2, DB1.rn1_
, DB2.rowid_, DB2.c1, DB2.c2, DB2.rn2_
from ( 
  select c1, c2 
  , row_number() over ( partition by c1, c2 order by c1 ) rn1_  -- {1}
  from db1 
) DB1 right join (                                              -- {3}
  select rowid as rowid_, c1, c2                                -- {2}
  , row_number() over ( partition by c1, c2 order by c1 ) rn2_  -- {1}
  from db2
) DB2 on DB1.c1 = DB2.c1 and DB1.c2 = DB2.c2 and DB1.rn1_ = DB2.rn2_
where DB1.c1 is null and DB1.c2 is null ;

-- result
C1   C2     RN1_ ROWID_               C1   C2            RN2_ 
                 AAAT6DAAMAAACNzAAC   A    23-SEP-19        3 
                 AAAT6DAAMAAACNzAAD   A    23-SEP-19        4 
                 AAAT6DAAMAAACNzAAF   B    22-SEP-19        2
```

Resultset of the same query (as above), with the WHERE clause "commented out":

```
C1   C2            RN1_ ROWID_               C1   C2            RN2_ 
A    23-SEP-19        1 AAAT6DAAMAAACNzAAA   A    23-SEP-19        1 
A    23-SEP-19        2 AAAT6DAAMAAACNzAAB   A    23-SEP-19        2 
B    22-SEP-19        1 AAAT6DAAMAAACNzAAE   B    22-SEP-19        1 
                        AAAT6DAAMAAACNzAAC   A    23-SEP-19        3 
                        AAAT6DAAMAAACNzAAD   A    23-SEP-19        4 
                        AAAT6DAAMAAACNzAAF   B    22-SEP-19        2
```

If this looks okay, then SELECT the DB2.rowid_ values (only), and use them in the WHERE clause of a DELETE:

```
SQL> delete db2
  2  where rowid in (
  3    select DB2.rowid_  -- select the rowid_ ONLY!
  4    from ( 
  5      select c1, c2 
  6      , row_number() over ( partition by c1, c2 order by c1 ) rn1_
  7      from db1 
  8    ) DB1 right join ( 
  9      select rowid as rowid_, c1, c2 
 10      , row_number() over ( partition by c1, c2 order by c1 ) rn2_
 11      from db2
 12    ) DB2 on DB1.c1 = DB2.c1 and DB1.c2 = DB2.c2 and DB1.rn1_ = DB2.rn2_
 13    where DB1.c1 is null and DB1.c2 is null
 14  ) ;

3 rows deleted.
```

The DB2 table now contains:

```
SQL> select * from DB2 ;
C1   C2          
A    23-SEP-19   
A    23-SEP-19   
B    22-SEP-19
```

**modifications**

In order to avoid difficulties with NULLs, use this modified DELETE statement:

```
delete db2
where rowid in (  
  select DB2.rowid_ 
  from ( 
    select to_char( c1 ) || to_char( c2 ) 
    || to_char(  row_number() over ( partition by c1, c2 order by c1 ) ) concat1
    from db1 
  ) DB1 
  right join ( 
    select rowid as rowid_
    , to_char( c1 ) || to_char( c2 ) 
    || to_char(  row_number() over ( partition by c1, c2 order by c1 ) ) concat2
    from db2
  ) DB2 on DB1.concat1 = DB2.concat2
  where DB1.concat1 is null
) ;
```

Tested with Oracle 18c and 19c - see example @ [livesql](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/i04xsa82ctke37zoxpvbbhybt).

Comment: This worked initially. But then I inserted duplicate rows into the remote table selecting from already existing rows in that table (insert into t2@dbl select * from t2@dbl where rownum=1). Re-ran the delete on source table and it didn't sync it the second time.

Comment: Btw, this solution works only if the second column (c2) is not null. If it is null then it deleted all rows from the remote table. These columns may or may not be null.

Comment: @VincyWales {1} insert ... select ... : seems fine when using 19c (sample tables on the same server, though) - see livesql statements 11-15. {2} Please try the modified version, see livesql link: statements 5,6: tables 1 and 2. Statement 7: rowids which will be deleted. Statements 9,10: tables 1 and 2 after DELETE.

Comment: This worked perfectly !! ... thanks a lot ... for me it also worked without using to_char function, c2 column and concatenation ... just need to add "and DB1.c1 = DB2.c1" on join condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to apply a unique row number to each row in both T1 and T2 which have the same C1 value, ordering it by C2 - then use MINUS to eliminate the duplicates:

```
SELECT C1, C2
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM (SELECT T2.*,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY C2) AS RNUM
                  FROM T2)
        MINUS
        (SELECT T1.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY C2) AS RNUM
           FROM T1))
```

This produces

```
C1  C2
A   23-SEP-19
A   23-SEP-19
B   22-SEP-19
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a49dbe45da2c05e95880a4b4e5f24046)

Comment: This works, but using `ROW_NUMBER()` like this produces non-deterministic results since the sort criteria is not sufficient to disambiguate the results...

Comment: This displays the desired result set. How to retain them and delete the rest from the remote db is the question.